# class type in std::map and std::unordered_set

Tags: c++

I was wondering why std::map allows the node to be user-defined type but std::unordered_set doesn't? 
As far as I understand, I assumed std::map is implemented using a binary tree and std::unordered_set is  a hashtable.

For instance

```
struct foo{
 int a;
 int b;
};

std::map<int,foo> m; //it is allowed, foo is the tree node that is value from the <int,foo> <key,value> pair
```

However, the same doesn't compile on std::unordered_set

```
std::underedset_set<foo> s //failed, "declaration of std::unordered_set<foo> s shadows a parameter"
```

which is weird to me since I consider foo is the value from the < key,value > in the hastable as well, and they are all template parameter of type Class K in the declaration. Thank you very much

```
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
       class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
       class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
       class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
       > class map;

template < class Key,                        // unordered_set::key_type/value_type
       class Hash = hash<Key>,           // unordered_set::hasher
       class Pred = equal_to<Key>,       // unordered_set::key_equal
       class Alloc = allocator<Key>      // unordered_set::allocator_type
       > class unordered_set;
```

**EDIT1:**

```
std::unordered_set<foo> s // failed again for different reason, which was really what I was asking

In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:3032:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/random:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algo.h:67,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/algorithm:63,
                 from ArrayTargetSum.cpp:10:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/functional_hash.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::hash<foo>’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/unordered_set.h:279:11:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<foo>’
ArrayTargetSum.cpp:70:25:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/functional_hash.h:60:7: error: static assertion failed: std::hash is not specialized for this type
```

I guess from the printout, the reason is that the user defined type is not hashable by the stl::hash function? Thanks

Comment: Try to rename 's' to something meaningful, say 's2'. :)

Comment: The value type of elements of a (unordered)set has the same requirements as the type of the keys of an (unordered)map.

Comment: Becuase you mipselled the tpyename, "underedset_set"?

Comment: One is a map and the other is a set. What do you mean by "std::map allows the node to be user-defined"?

Comment: Once you fix the problems pointed out in other comments, my first comment will start making some sense :-)

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod this reason was that I was convinced the std::unordered_set is implemented as a hashtable internally. I assumed in std::unordered_set<TYPE> TYPE could be user-defined type that is "mapped" somewhere in the hashtable

Comment: @CongHui, see this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set "Unordered set is an associative container that contains set of unique objects of type Key. Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity. 

Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to individual elements, since once hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket the element is placed into."

Comment: @CongHui: So the mistake you made is in thinking about implementation details when you have no idea what they are, instead of following the pre-requisites listed in the documentation for this abstracted piece of functionality. i.e. research about `unordered_set`, not about hashtables or trees or anything else you'd like to make guesses about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was confused by the definition of unordered_map, since I remembered I've seen a hashtable implementation somewhere, I guess it was unordered_map. ***Unordered_map:Unordered containers organize their elements using hash tables that allow for fast access to elements by their key.*** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Comment: @CongHui: Yes but you're missing my point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "declaration of std::unordered_set s shadows a parameter"

That has nothing to do with the set.

You're giving it the same name as a function parameter.

Rename it.

Do make sure your value type has an associated hash and equality functions, though; recall that for your map your *key* type needed an ordering function.

Comment: I guess I was totally ignoring the fact that I didn't supply a customized hash function for my struct. Care to point out where I might be able to find some examples for using a user-defined hash functions? Thanks

Comment: @CongHui, one thing you can try is convert all your data members to strings, concatenate, and use hash<string>.